# C Program infinite loop unexpectedly when used scanf

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop

I checked here and there and wasted around 3 hours checking for a solution. My program just infinite loop itself. Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)

{
    int attempts = 0;
    char password[10];

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your password:\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", password);
        printf("\n");
        attempts++;
    } while (strcmp(password, "awesome 123 ok"));

    printf("You entered a correct password in %d attempts!", attempts);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried `scanf("%[A-Za-z0-9 ]s", password)"`so it can take all characters and numbers including space as an input but it just loop. And I also tried using `getchar()` but it asks for password again and again even if I enter the correct one. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the `s` in the format `"%[^\n]s"`. Use just `"%[^\n]"`.

Comment: Obligatory: Check return value of all `scanf` functions, always.

Comment: Just check it out your scanf syntax. probably you can also use gets(password) or correct the scanf("%[^\n]", password);

Comment: @Avinash No no no, never advice anyone to use `gets`. It's prone to buffer overflows, have been deprecated in the C standard for long, and even removed in the latest C11 standard.

Comment: @Avinash Never use `gets`! It's broken, deprecated, finally removed in C11. Use for example `fgets` or non-standard `getline` instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just entered "C" tag and I'm not sure where other tags came from.

Comment: @Amession Ah sorry, someone else edited the tags. I've removed it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Size of `awesome 123 ok` is 15 including `\0`. But you are allocating memory for 10 bytes. It causes undefined behavior.

When you are using `%[^\n]` format specifier no need to use `s` with that, It will automatically scan the spaces also.

Try the following changes-

```
int main (void)

{
    int attempts = 0;
    char password[20]; // Fix 1

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your password:\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]", password); // Fix 2
        printf("\n");
        attempts++;
    } while (strcmp(password, "awesome 123 ok"));

    printf("You entered a correct password in %d attempts!", attempts);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2 problems: 1) If user enters `"\n"`, `password` will have random data in it.  2) On second loop, the first line's `"\n"` remains in `stdin`. blocking any new entry.   Suggest `fgets()`.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `char password[10];` but you compare it with `awesome 123 ok` which has more characters.

Comment: oh! this is embarrassing for me. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 3):

From [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters before attempting to parse the input.

That means that the trailing newline (a whitespace character) will be included in the next call to `scanf` in the loop.

The solution is simple: Tell `scanf` to read and discard leading whitespace:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", password);
/*     ^              */
/*     |              */
/* Note leading space */
```

Also note that I removed the trailing `s` in the format, because that tells `scanf` to expect a literal `s` in the input. The `"%["` format ends with the closing `']'`.

---

You also might want to limit the number of characters read so you don't overflow the buffer you read into:

```
scanf(" %9[^\n]", password);
```

Note that the above format set the maximum field width as nine characters, because the buffer needs to include the terminating `'\0'` character as well. Modify this number if you increase the buffer size, but remember that it should be (at most) one less than the buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

Change the dec password[10] to password[20]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `password` is too narrow. Because of this, the program routinely writes past the end of the array, resulting in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can fix this by making `password` wider. However, your program will still be open to [stack smashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow): an attacker can potentially execute arbitrary code by entering a long carefully crafted password string.

To fix that, you need to change the `scanf()` format specifier to limit how many characters it can store in `password`.

The following changes will fix both:

```
    char password[32]; /* more space: 31 characters + NUL */
    do {
        ...
        scanf("%31[^\n]%*c", password); /* format specifier */
```

The latter will make sure you're never reading more than 31 characters into `password`; it also consumes the newline without storing it.

Comment: What does the %*c do? is it same as %c?

Comment: @Amession: Yes, except it doesn't store it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use fgets because it is a safer way than gets or scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int attempts = 0;
    char password[20];

    do {
        printf("Enter your password:\n");
        fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
        password[strlen(password) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("\n");
        attempts++;
    } while (strcmp(password, "awesome 123 ok"));
    printf("You entered a correct password in %d attempts!", attempts);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this will only work if you increase the size of password[] as I did in my example. When not using fgets it might still work in a bad way because you are comparing a buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks, fgets is new for me, I learned something new today! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `getchar()` to consume the `\n` character. Find the modified code in below.

```
int main (void)

{
    int attempts = 0;
    char password[10];

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your password:\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", password);
        getchar (); // Fix1

        printf("\n");
        attempts++;
    } while (strcmp(password, "awesome 123 ok"));

    printf("You entered a correct password in %d attempts!", attempts);

    return 0;
}
```

The array `password` is not used properly in your code. So change the logic for it. User can enter N numbers of character. So restrict the user input to limited character or use dynamic memory allocation